# Vault gives old and new values for keys

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, kubernetes-helm

I am using Hashicorp's Vault which is deployed in a kubernetes cluster on AWS using the available helm chart and created the default `3 pods` for my vault deployment. The vault's store is in AWS S3.

I am accessing this service from another deployment using port forwarding of kubernetes internal IP.

Now when I write to the vault(version 1 kv) using the command:
`vault kv put something/abc key={"x","y","z"}`, I get the earlier values at times when I do a `vault kv get something/abc`.

If earlier the value for `key` was `{"x","y"}`.

I get the older value in some of my `get` calls and the newer values in other calls.(I am making these `get` calls from the same pod).
I get (say), `key=[x y z]` in the first get call, 
`key=[x y]` in the second get call,
`key=[x y]` in the third one; and this repeats.

(All pods were in the `Ready(1/1)` state. Because I had set the `--set vault.readiness.readyIfSealed=true` in the helm chart.
Without setting that, only one pod goes in ready state(1/1). Others are in `Ready(0/1)` state. In this case I get the newer updated value in all my `get` calls)

Any idea why I am not getting the same new value returned for every call?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What values you get when you make the first get? What do you mean with "Then I get the older value in some of my get calls and the newer values in other calls"? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post. I hope it answers your question. Thanks

My point was that I am also getting the older values for that key. Which should not happen. Also the values returned followed a pattern based on the number of pods. Thanks